# How to create BigQuery Procedure that passes in table as alias to use any field?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, bigquery-udf

I have the following function in postgres:

```
create function my_function(my_table mt, OUT e_p_l numeric, OUT e_p numeric) returns record
    language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
    e_p_l := e_p_procedure(mt.p, mt.q_l, mt.m_c, mt.d_f);
    e_p := e_p_procedure(mt.p, mt.q, mt.m_c, mt.d_f);
END;
$$;
```

I have e_p_procedure successfully working in BigQuery. But the current error I have is

```
Type not found: mt
```

my_table is just as it seems, a table (aliased as mt) with various fields I'd like to input into a BigQuery Procedure replica of this Postgres function.

How can I accomplish this in BigQuery?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_schema.my_function(my_table mt, OUT e_p_l numeric, OUT e_p numeric) 
BEGIN
    SET e_p_l = e_p_procedure(mt.p, mt.q_l, mt.m_c, mt.d_f);
    SET e_p = e_p_procedure(mt.p, mt.q, mt.m_c, mt.d_f);
END;
```

Comment: do you have the mt data type defined?

Comment: I can't answer for BigQuery, but I can tell you that passing a table as an argument of a function is not allowed in sql nor in plpgsql. You can pass the table name as a text parameter and then execute a dynamic sql statement in your function and which will create the resulting query at run time see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). Then instead of `SET = ...` in the function, you have to use `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM ....` see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-selectinto.html)

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, you can execute dynamic statements in BigQuery by using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` syntax to pass table values within your `PROCEDURE`.

Your script would look something like,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_dataset.my_procedure(tableName STRING, ...) 
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT("SELECT column_name FROM ", tableName, " WHERE ...");
  ...
END
```

You can find more examples on how to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) for different use cases. Additionally, here's a documentation for [creating procedure](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure) in BigQuery.